# SQL Server 2016 Express: System databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

As per recommended practice, on a new server that I have created with SQL Server 2016 Express SP1, I am trying to move the system databases OFF the C: drive onto E: and F: drives (the MDF's onto E: and the LDF's onto F:). Is this possible with the EXPRESS version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to move the system database for *Express* just like any other edition.  [Move System Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx) contains very straightforward instructions on the steps required to move the system databases.

For future reference, you can [specify the storage locations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547.aspx) of the system database at install time and save yourself some time.